# Windows 8 hybrid shutdown disables BIOS setup

Tags: windows-8, bios, grub

My Lenovo laptop runs Windows 8 and Linux Mint with GRUB bootloader.
Today, I have deleted Mint partition from Windows and by mistake shut down my laptop instead of rebooting it.
Now I cannot change my boot priority to load from dvd.
Is there any way to unlock BIOS, and boot into any OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found the solution when I ejected the battery preparing to disassemble the laptop.

It somehow reseted this shutdown thing.
Then I just booted from disc and restored the MBR.

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid Boot is basically a Logoff + Hibernation. In Hibernation the access to BIOS is disabled to avoid resume issues. Start the Windows 8 again and select reboot or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the shutdown button in the Charms to do a full shutdown.